# How to solve motion question?

Tags: trigonometry

A particle is moving at $x=3\cos\left(2t\right)$. Find the expression for velocity in terms of $x$.

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Do you know that velocity is the derivative of $x(t)$?

Comment: @GregorBruns If I differentiate the function, wouldn't that give me the velocity but in terms of t instead of x?

Comment: Yes, it does. But there is the relation $\sin(s)^2+\cos(s)^2=1$, which applies also to $s=2t$, that is $\sin(2t)^2+\cos(2t)^2=1$. You have to play around a little bit with the numbers, though. In this way you can express $v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$ in terms of $x(t)$.

Comment: @GregorBruns Thanks for that! I'll have a play around and see if I can find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, here's a slightly cleaner version of previous answers.  We have

$$x=3\cos 2t,\frac{dx}{dt}=-6\sin 2t$$

Again, we use the trig identity

$$\sin^2u+\cos^2u=1$$

Substituting $u=2t$ we have

$$\sin^2 2t+\cos^2 2t=1$$

Now we multiply this equation by 9.

$$9\sin^22t+9\cos^22t=9$$

$$9\sin^22t+x^2=9$$

$$9\sin^22t=9-x^2$$

$$3\sin2t=\pm\sqrt{9-x^2}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-6\sin 2t=\pm2\sqrt{9-x^2}$$

The plus or minus depends on the value of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the velocity is the derivative of the displacement we are looking for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in terms of x
$$x=3\cos(2t)$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-6\sin(2t)$$
Solving for $t$ in the first equation shows that
$$t=\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$$
Using the following trig identity 
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$
and solving for $\sin x$ gives
$$\sin x=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$$
Therefore, plugging in for $t$ in the second equation gives
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-6\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm6\sqrt{1-\cos^2\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm6\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{9}}$$
$$\fbox{$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm2\sqrt{9-x^2}$}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$\dot x(t)=-6\sin(2t)$$
From the equation:
$$x(t)=3\cos(2t)$$
you have:
$$t=\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{x(t)}{3}\right)$$
So:
$$\dot x(t)=-6\sin\left(\arccos\frac{x(t)}{3}\right)$$